# menu toggle with BS3 and nav-pills

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to image_tag("erb_logo.png", alt: "Eco Rebox"), root_path, class: "mainlogo navbar-brand" %>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse1">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'first' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'News', posts_path, class: 'blog' %></li>
        <li class="dropdown second">
          <a href="about" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            About <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Company Profile', about_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Our Customers', companies_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'What People Are Saying', testimonials_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown third">
          <a href="logistics" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Solutions <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Software', software_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Sustainability', rethink_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Logistics & Methodology', restore_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown fourth">
          <a href="products" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Products <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Reusable Boxes', reuse_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Shipping Containers', shipping_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: 'fifth' %></li>
        <% if signed_in? %>
        <li class="dropdown sixth">
          <a href="user" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            My Account <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
          </ul>
        </li> 
        <% else %>  
        <li><a href="#signinModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Sign in</a></li>
        <% end %> 
      </ul>
    </div> <!--/.navbar-header -->
  </div> <!--/.container -->
</nav>
```

So... That's a header menu... but not the default.  http://www.ecorebox.com/ - You can see it there.  I'm trying to get the responsive menu to work.  I've set it up before, but with the default-navbar.  That `<navbar-header>` section should be rendering a button to show/hide the menu when in xs mode, I believe.  I can't seem to get it to work, though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse1">
```

That above is not wrapped around the menu.

However, you have other errors. Run it through a validator, fix errors. Make sure the collapse is surrounding the thing you want collapsed.

There's nothing showing up for icon-bar, so you need to fix that also pills don't stack at small sizes, but here it works.

http://jsbin.com/USEhecUZ/1/

Comment: That div was wrapped around the menu... but what's different about yours is you wrapped the `.navbar-hearder` around the entire menu, and that definitely works.  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default - the documentation doesn't show that.  And, apparently the icon bar is nested in `.navbar-default`, so I pulled out some of the CSS and styled it accordingly.  Thanks!